# What is in Google static maps image PropertyItem 20738?

Tags: image-processing, google-maps-static-api, propertyinfo

When a map image is served from Google static maps, the image contains a number of propertyItems, one of which (20738) is quite long and might possibly, if I'm lucky, contain information that I need regarding the edge coordinates of the returned map.

The data is clearly encoded in some way (it's not text!).  Does anyone know what this data contains and how to decode it?

Thanks.

Comment: Surely someone out there must know?  I don't have enough reputation to offer a bounty!

Answer (score 0):

Property item 20738 contains the global colour palette for the image. It's a byte array so won't be any use to you for that.